# Add or Remove multiple list item on the basis of AND,OR,NOT conditions in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to add multiple add or remove multiple rules on the basis of AND/OR/NOT operators. For example: rule1>12h && rule2<10h. How can we do that?

```
<label class="control-label" for="field_notificationRules">Notification 
Filter Rules:</label>

    <div class="form-group">
        <table class="table table-stripped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><label class="control-label" for="field_filterRuleDefinition">Rule Definition</label></th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="notificationFilterRulesDefinition" id="field_filterRuleDefinition" ng-model="vm.notificationRules.notificationRules.notificationFilterRules.notificationFilterRulesDefinition"/>
                </td>
                <td><button class="btn fa fa-plus" ng-click="addNewFilterRow()">Add</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-show="filterShow">
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="notificationFilterRulesDefinition" id="field_filterRuleDefinition" ng-model="vm.notificationRules.notificationRules.notificationFilterRules.notificationFilterRulesDefinition"/>
                </td>
                <td><button class="btn fa fa-plus" ng-click="addNewFilterRow()">Add</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: where is your related condition code?

Comment: Please upload your js code or where you want to implement your logic?